# Create custom script for send mail in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email

We want to create one php file.
When we run it from front side then send mail.
We don't want to create module.
We also wand to use magento 1.9 default functionality.

Any one help me for create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create send.php file into root folder.

```
    require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
            $html=" Write your Content Here

            ";
            $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
            $mail->setToName('Your Name');
            $mail->setToEmail('YoueEmail@gmail.com');
            $mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
            $mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
            $mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
            $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
            $mail->setType('html');// You can use Html or text as Mail format
            $mail->setBodyHTML($html);  // your content or message

            if($mail->send()){
                echo 'Your request has been sent';
            } else {
               echo 'Unable to send.';
            }
```

Comment: It's working as per my requirement. Thanks

Comment: for me it is redirecting to search page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this script to your custom .php file and you can run it in browser.

```
require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$msg = "your message";
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
```